# Calculating the time it takes for a particle to move using a gamma function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, gamma-function, classical-mechanics

> Calculate the time it takes a point particle of mass $m$ to roll down a log 
>   potential, $ V(x) = \frac{V_0}{2}ln\frac{x}{x_0}$ using incomplete gamma function. The particle starts at position $x_0$ at time $t=0$ with energy $E=0$, and falls all the way into the singularity at $x=0$.

ok so I tried solving using conservation of energy:

$E = T + V$

$E(x) = \frac{1}{2}m\ddot r$  + $\frac{V_0}{2}ln\frac{x}{x_0}$

with initial conditions:

$r(0) = x_0$;  $E = 0$

Plug in:

$0 = \frac{1}{2}m x_0$ + $\frac{V_0}{2}ln\frac{x}{x_0}$

$-mx_0$ = $v_0 ln\frac{x}{x_0}$

From here how do you proceed using a gamma function? to be honest I have no idea how to solve this problem with using a gamma function.. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean to say "the incomplete Gamma function," not the "Gamma function?"

Comment: thanks for a comment, I am not entirely sure whether it's lower or upper incomplete gamma function.

Comment: to be honest I am not even sure if this question can be solved using gamma function... any piece of advice where I should start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From conservation of energy, we have

$$\frac12m \dot x^2+V_0\log(x/x_0)=0 $$

Solving $(1)$, we find

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\sqrt{-\frac{2V_0}{m}\log(x/x_0)}\tag 1$$

Proceeding to integrate $(1)$ reveals

$$\int_0^{x(t)} \left(-\frac{2V_0}{m}\log(x'/x_0)\right)^{-1/2}\,dx'=t$$

Then, enforcing the substitutuion $x'= x_0e^{-s}$ yields

$$\begin{align}
t&=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2V_0}}x_0\int_{-\log(x(t)/x_0)}^\infty s^{-1/2}e^{-s}\,ds\\\\
&=\Gamma\left(\frac12,-\log(x(t)/x_0)\right)
\end{align}$$

where $\Gamma(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the Upper Incomplete Gamma Function.

Comment: Thanks for the calculation really appreciate it. I do get up to third part, can you explain bit more from 3rd part to 4th part? where you do the substitution?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  In the substitution $x'=x_0e^{-s}$, note that $dx'=-x_0e^{-s}$ and the lower and upper limits become $\infty$ and $-\log(x(t)/x_0)$.  Then, absorbing the minus sign while "flipping" the limits, we arrive a the fourth line.